# In Android 8.0 and 8.1.0, I am unable to install the APK from drive directly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-8.0-oreo

I just installed oreo, set it up. works great! There is a minor issue though, I can't install APK from google drive by just tapping them I need to download them and then install. It says there was a **problem parsing the package**. Why is this happening? Can anyone suggest me?